# Rails generate model --orm option missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to generate a model using the next sentence:

```
rails g model SupplyRequestProfile name:string{50} active:boolean
```

It fails, and shows the next single line

**No value provided for option '--orm'**

But, when I use, skipping the fields and types:

```
rails g model SupplyRequestProfile
```

It does the job and all is normal.

I have looked if I use a reserved word of rails for my propertys in http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/ but there is no one that im using.

The problem is not the config/application.rb, all is ok there.

So, I dont know what could be happen here, but it is like some of my property names or types are wrong or causing some strange behavior on rails generation.

What could be wrong?

Comment: So, I found the solution to my own question. I simple put the fields names and types inside double quotes and all works perfect.

Comment: rails generate model SupplyRequestProfile "name:string{50}" "active:boolean" will work

Comment: You can post an answer, it may help others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply putting the fields names with their types inside double quotes will work:

```
rails generate model SupplyRequestProfile "name:string{50}" "active:boolean"
```